# Numbers-matlab-to which number does it correspond

Tags: notation, matlab

I have written a code in matlab and got this result for something I calculated: 1.3000e+003
To which number does my result correspond?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

${\tt  1.3000e+003=1.3000\cdot 10^3=1300}$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$

Comment: I got it...thank you very much...

Comment: @evinda no problem...